# Efficient indexing when index must cycle

Tags: function-construction

I've defined a function indexed through a cycle:

```
$Assumptions = 
 n > 3 && n \[Element] Integers && i \[Element] Integers && i <= n && 
  i >= 1
f[i_, n_] := c[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]] + c[Mod[i - 1, n, 1]] + c[Mod[i - 1, n, 1]] + c[Mod[i + 2, n, 1]] + c[Mod[i - 2, n, 1]]
```

Once the index $i$ reaches $n$, $i+1$ returns $1$, $i+2$ returns $2$ etc. Is there a more efficient way of defining it?

Comment: The `Mod[i, n, 1]` construct is pretty much the best way to do what you want.

Comment: slightly shorter/cleaner way: `g[i_, n_] :=Total[c /@ Mod[Range[i - 2, i + 2], n, 1]]`?